# How to convert string without delimiter to list in python

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

So I have string like this:

```
"UFFKTEWKW"
```

And I need to convert it to a list or tuple like this:

```
("UFF", "KTE", "WKW")
```

So every 3 letters from the string goes to separate element of list or tuple.

I can't use split() here because string doesn't have any delimiters. I don't wanna make some dummy for cycle for it. And I think there should be simple solution for it.

Comment: since string supports the exact same slicing mechanism as list, same solutions apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
a="UFFKTEWKW"
out=tuple(a[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(a),3))
# ('UFF', 'KTE', 'WKW')
```